# Changing the sequence in Liquibase with oracle

Tags: liquibase

I have a table `X` created in Liquibase a few years ago without a sequence. Recently, a correction was attempted by doing the following steps:

- Created a sequence with `startValue=2000`;
- Created a new temp table(Y) with that sequence on the ID column;
- Moved all the data from table X into table Y;
- Dropped table X;
- Renamed table Y to X;

---

Now those changes were pushed to prod. And they asked me to change that `sequence` from 2000 to 2050.

I never worked with Liquibase prior; my thought is to drop that sequence and create a new sequence with `startValue=2050`.

But I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way worked for me:

```
<changeSet  author="ml"  id="20200730-sequence">  
    <dropSequence  sequenceName="seq_id"/>  
    <createSequence    
            sequenceName="seq_id"
            startValue="2050"
            incrementBy="1"  
            ordered="true"/> 
</changeSet>
```